# Заменить все теги на p

Tags: php

Имеется HTML-разметка в текстовой переменной. Как можно заменить все теги в этой разметке на тег `p`? Есть ли стандартные функции PHP для этого? `strip_tags()` не подходит, так как просто убирает теги, а нужно именно заменить.

Comment: Используйте стандартную функцию `preg_replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = '<div>DIV</div>
<a href="">A</a>
<span>SPAN</span>';
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//body/*');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    if($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
        $p = $dom->createElement('p', $node->nodeValue);
        $node->parentNode->replaceChild($p, $node);
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: спасибо. Все бы хорошо, да русские буквы в результирующей строке выводятся в виде иероглифов...

Comment: @nup, замените эту строку `$dom->loadHTML($str);` на эту `$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $str);`

Comment: спасибо, это помогло.

Comment: если можно, еще вопрос по этому же коду. Как можно в этом же цикле удалить все заголовки (h1-h3)?

Comment: @nup, в цикле измените: `if($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
  if(preg_match('/^h[1-6]$/',$node->tagName)) {
         $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
  } else {
   $p = $dom->createElement('p', $node->nodeValue);
         $node->parentNode->replaceChild($p, $node);
  }
    }`

Comment: спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @nup, только сейчас заметил, что вам удалить надо заголовки до H3 включительно, поэтому регулярку подправьте: `/^h[1-3]$/`

Answer (score 1):

Как насчёт варианта с `str_replace`?
[Ссылка на документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)